# Change PrimeFaces DataGrid (responsive mode) behaviour

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

It seems that DataGrid PrimeFaces component (responsive mode) starts out stacked on small devices and becomes horizontal when resolution grows beyond 640 px. I want to 
be able to choose the width from which DataGrid columns stop being stacked and start positioning one beside the other. That is, change the 640 px default value 
to any other value of my choice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default breakpoint is 35em which equals to 560px. You need to override the css in PrimeFaces which is by default;

```
/* Responsive */
@media (max-width:35em){
    .ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-row {
        display:block;
    }
    .ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-1,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-2,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-3,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-4,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-5,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-6,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-7,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-8,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-9,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-10,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-11,.ui-grid-responsive .ui-grid-col-12 {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Source:  Primefaces PRO support queried in private form about DataTable component of PF 5.2 on June 2015 (similar answer, different css classes, tested these on PrimeFaces 5.3 online showcase)